# Best method of removing flattish areas of a signal in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, signals

Say I have a signal that looks a bit like this: [image]

that I am processing in MatLab, what functions would I have to use to get rid of the flattish area in the middle? is there any functions that can do that, or do I need to program it in myself? Currently I just have a blank function as I don't know where to start:

```
function  removala = removal(a, b)

end
```

Is there any quick functions that can remove it or do I just have to search for all values below a threshold and remove them myself? For reference a and b are vectors of amplitude points.

Comment: You probably need to start by coming up with an objective definition of "flattish" ;)

Comment: Anything below 0.75, that's in between the peaks

Comment: How would you "remove" these points?  Would you set them to zero or subset your vector so that they disappear from your output (i.e. a subsampling)?

Comment: Subset the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `findpeaks`:

```
% generating signal
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = rand(size(x))*0.5;
y([5,25,84]) = [6,-5.5,7.5];
z = y;
thresh = 0.75; % height threshold
% find peaks
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(z,'MinPeakProminence',thresh);
% remove signal noise between peaks
for ii = 1:length(locs)-1
    zz = z(locs(ii)+1:locs(ii+1)-1);
    zz(abs(zz) < thresh) = 0;
    z(locs(ii)+1:locs(ii+1)-1) = zz;
end
% plot
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(x,z);
plot(x(locs),pks,'og');
legend('original signal','modified signal','peaks')
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, sets me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to remove the signal whose absolute power is less than a certain threshold. 
So the two input of your function would be the raw signal, and the threshold. The function will output a variable "cleanSignal"

```
function cleanSignal = removal(rawSignal,threshold)
```

simplest implementation. remove the data below threshold. If rawSignal is a matrix the resulting variable will be a vector concatenating all the epochs above threshold.

```
ind = abs(rawSignal)<threshold;
rawSignal(ind) = []; 
cleanSignal = rawSignal;
```

This might not be the behavior that you want, since you want to preserve the original shape of your rawSignal matrix. So you can just "nan" the values below threshold.

```
ind = abs(rawSignal)<threshold;
rawSignal(ind) = nan; 
cleanSignal = rawSignal;
end
```

Notice that this does not really removes flat signal, but signal which is close to 0. 
If you really want to remove flat signal you should use

```
ind = abs(diff(rawSignal))<threshold;
```